# Fragment is not fully displayed when used in activity with actionbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-actionbar

In my activity (ConstraintLayout) I have an actionbar and a container (for my viewpage adapater). In this container I am displaying various fragments. 
My problem is that the fragments (also in ConstraintLayout) are not completely displayed, meaning they are cut off at the end. My assumption is that this happens because the fragment "doesnt know" about the action bar in the activity and thus thinks it has the full screen to use but instead this part which the action bar takes up is moved down and off from the screen. That's just an assumption maybe I am completely wrong. Anybody can help on how to make sure the fragment layout is somehow "fitted" right to the screen?

my activity xml with the actionbar:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context=".TourActivity">

<include
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    layout="@layout/app_bar"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"></include>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/app_bar" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

the fragment xml:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".TourActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:layout_width="388dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="testtest testtest"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.52"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="365dp"
    android:layout_height="185dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/question"
    tools:src="@android:color/darker_gray" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/answerButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="156dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="answerButton1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/answerButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="answerButton2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/answerButton1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/answerButton3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="answerButton3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/answerButton2" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"

    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/app_bar"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
```

Pls give that a go.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately it doesnt really work. If I run it it doesn't show anything of the fragment. Checking in the design I see the container is somehow lying below the app bar and has about the same size as the appbar.
What was your idea when posting this? Maybe I can refine it a little to find the solution

Comment: That could be because your *app_bar* is using *android:layout_height="match_parent"*. That looks dubious to me. You can play with that I feel. At the least, you should wrap it around content. Can you do that and see if it works. Let me know.

Comment: My app_bar height is set to wrap_content in the app_bar.xml so i dont know if thats the issue..
or do you mean setting to wrap_content somewhere else?

Comment: I mistook your fragment to be your app_bar. My bad. Another potential issue I noticed, *android:layout_height="wrap_content"* in your activity. That should be *match_parent*.

Comment: Unfortunately still not working even with the changed height in the activity.
There must be a way to display an appbar and fragment without the fragment being out of the screen?

Answer (score 0):

Use Relative Layout in the main XML file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".TourActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/app_bar" />
</RelativeLayout>
```